# What to stop timer when I get out the page

Tags: c#, timer

I have to ASP.NET pages, Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx.
In Page2.aspx.cs I have a timer invoked in PageLoad:

```
timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
timer1.AutoReset = true; 
timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Tick;
timer1.Start();
```

When I go from Page2 to Page1 in my browser, I have identified that timer1 is executing while I'm browsing in Page1. What is the best way to stop timer1 where I go out from Page2.

Thank you and sorry for my English, I try my best.

Comment: Don't try to use `System.Timers.Timer`. It's got no idea about Pages, the ASP.Net request lifecycle, etc. Almost always a better idea to be running a timer *on the page*, via javascript's `setInterval`.

Comment: But I need to run timer in C#..

Comment: Why?  Your page lives in the browser, what good is a timer on the server?

Comment: Because I have to use non static variables... And if I use setInterval, I have to use Ajax -> static C# function -> can't use non static functions and variables

Comment: @DanielR - This sounds like an X-Y problem. What are you really trying to solve?

Comment: If you are doing this just to learn, I would strongly suggest to skip WebForms (aspx) and move over to MVC.

Comment: Well.. Finally I have got with setInterval same functionality. Thank you all.